# C/C++: Size of builtin types for various compilers/platforms

Tags: c++, c, sizeof, built-in

Where can I go to get information about the size of, say, `unsigned int` compiling under `gcc` for Mac OS X (both 32 and 64 bits)? In general I'd love to have a resource I can go to with a compiler/settings/platform/type and be able to look up how big that type will be. Does anyone know of such a thing?

Update: Thanks for all the responses. I was hoping to have something more along the lines of a static table somewhere instead of a piece of code I'd have to write and run on every machine.

Comment: This is kind of a dupe, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/589575/c-size-of-int-long-etc

Comment: If you can write your code without making assumptions about the sizes of the types, it will work everywhere.

Comment: if you are using C99 (to be honest, some c++ standard libraries have it too, at the very least boost offers it) you can use `stdint.h`. It offers things like `int8_t` which is guaranteed to be 8-bits big.

Comment: Just to add to pmg's comment, the standard mandates minimum sizes for the integral types (broadly speaking, 8 bit, 16 bit, 16 bit, 32 bit and 64 bit for `char`, `short`, `int`, `long` and `long long` respectively), which is often all you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can't write a program to find out, you should consult the ABI (Application Binary Interface) specification for the compiler/platform. It should document the sizes, alignments, endianness, etc. of the basic primitive types supported.

Answer (score 9):

Generic method of sambowry's method (C++):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

template <typename T>
void print_sizeof(void)
{
    std::cout << "sizeof(" <<
        typeid(T).name() << ") == " <<
        sizeof(T) << std::endl;
}

int main(void)
{
    print_sizeof<short>();
    print_sizeof<unsigned int>();
    print_sizeof<long>();
    print_sizeof<long long>();
    print_sizeof<uint64_t>();
}
```

Note the compiler isn't required to give you an actual string for name, but most do.

Answer (score 7):

In general, you don't need to know exact sizes if you include `stdint.h`. There are defined several very useful types.

If you want exact size, use these:

```
int8_t
uint8_t
int16_t
uint16_t
int32_t
uint32_t
int64_t
uint64_t
```

If you want at least the specified size, use these:

```
int_least8_t
uint_least8_t
int_least16_t
uint_least16_t
int_least32_t
uint_least32_t
int_least64_t
uint_least64_t
```

If you want at least the specified size optimized for speed, use these:

```
int_fast8_t
uint_fast8_t
int_fast16_t
uint_fast16_t
int_fast32_t
uint_fast32_t
int_fast64_t
uint_fast64_t
```

Comment: Although beware that stdint.h is not necessarily available in C89 or C++, it's a C99 thing. Fortunately it is very commonly available. Where not provided by the compiler you can usually find a version of it for your platform, although that sort of begs the question since of course "finding a copy of stdint.h" is almost equivalent to "finding out how big the integer types are".

Comment: For Microsoft Visual C/C++, there's a decent version of `stdint.h` at http://msinttypes.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/stdint.h

Answer (score 6):

You may query the length of a data type with the sizeof operator. For example:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <inttypes.h> 

#define PRINT_SIZEOF(type)  printf("sizeof( " #type " ) == %zi\n", sizeof(type) )

int main(void){
  PRINT_SIZEOF( short        );
  PRINT_SIZEOF( unsigned int );
  PRINT_SIZEOF( long         );
  PRINT_SIZEOF( long long    );
  PRINT_SIZEOF( uint64_t     );
}
```

EDIT: %i changed to %zi

Comment: If `size_t` and `int` have different sizes, your printf may print erroneous information.

Comment: Fix is to replace `sizeof(type)` with `(int)(sizeof(type))`. The chances of the size of a long long overflowing an int is non-zero but negligible. It would have to be a just-for-kicks, barely-conformant implementation. In which case you also have to worry about the fact that it's entirely legal for `sizeof(long long) == 12` but `ULONGLONG_MAX` to be 2^64-1.

Answer (score 2):

You could write a test program that uses `sizeof` calls on all the types you're interested in. Might also be useful to check limits.h.

Answer (score 0):

you could probably write some simple shell script that prompts for a type and when you enter it it compiles something like what sambowry posted and executes it to tell you what the size of it is..