# Maximum values for Variables in C vs Java

Tags: java, c

I have a problem here asking me to display the minimum and maximum a variable can store including: Short, Integer, Long and Float. I’m supposed to initilize it with one less than the correct answer, then add 1 to it to prove the variable doesn’t give an error. 
Example.

```
short srtMaximum = 32766;
srtMaximum += 1;
System.out.print(”Max value for short is “ + srtMaximum);
```

I’m supposed to do this for C and Java. Java I did no problem. 
    Short is -32768, 32767
    Int is -2,147,483,648, 2,147,483,647
    Long -9quintillionL, 9 quintillionL
Float was something I can’t remember off the top of my head

But with C is where I’m confused.
Short seems to be the same. 
But Long can only hold the same value as an Int?
The documentation says an int can sometimes only be -32768 - 32767?

And I have no idea how to do this project with floats. No matter what value I assign the float to test it, it prints something different in printf

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for `c`'s `long long`?

Comment: (java)how about `Integer.MAX_VALUE`...?

Comment: In Java, the numeric types are of a fixed size everywhere. Hence there exists constants such as `Integer.MAX_VALUE` and `Integer.MIN_VALUE`. If memory serves, in C, only a minimum size for each type is [specified](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types) hence there is no direct comparison.

Comment: Generally in C, `sizeof(char) <= sizeof(short)`, `sizeof(short) <= sizeof(int)`, `sizeof(int) <= sizeof(long)`, and `sizeof(long) <= sizeof(long long)`. The C specification says that `sizeof(char)` will *always* be equal to `1, and that `long long` is at least a 64-bit type. You can find out [the limits](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/limits) for the current implementation/target by using `<stdint.h>` and `<limits.h>`

Comment: The limits in C are platform dependent.  The limits in Java are specified by the language, not the platform.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C/C++: Size of builtin types for various compilers/platforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457431/c-c-size-of-builtin-types-for-various-compilers-platforms)

Comment: This is the reason why stdint.h was invented. The default types in C are useless cross-platform, since you can't know how big they are.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [limits.h](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/basedefs/limits.h.html) to figure out what the largest integer values are on your system. You can use [float.h](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cfloat/) to figure out what the largest floating-point values are.

Here's an example for limits.h:

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("INT_MAX: %d\n", INT_MAX);
    printf("UINT_MAX: %u\n", UINT_MAX);
    printf("LONG_MAX: %ld\n", LONG_MAX);
    printf("ULONG_MAX: %lu\n", ULONG_MAX);
}
```

I am unsure what your instructor means by 'one less than the maximum float.' One less than the maximum float is not representable.

> No matter what value I assign the float to test it, it prints something different in printf

Floating point cannot represent all numbers precisely. Here's how to tell if you can represent it precisely:

1. Convert it to a fraction
2. Reduce the fraction
3. Check if the denominator is a power of two.

Example: Can `0.1` be precisely represented?

1. First, convert it to a fraction: `1/10`
2. Next, reduce: `1/10`
3. 10 is not a power of two. Therefore, `0.1` cannot be precisely represented.

Comment: `one less than the maximum float.` Java has a [`Math.ulp()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#ulp(double)) method with determines the smallest available change for a given floating point value.  Perhaps there's a library with a similar function for C?

Comment: use GMP : The GNU Multiple Precision Arithmetic Library. Will give you very high precision in C.